# Identifiability of a probability distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, integral-equations

Is the following distribution

$$P(\textbf{x}; \boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}) = \int_{\text{h} \in \mathbb{R}^d} N\left(\textbf{h}; \boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}\right) \,\text{Mult}\left(\textbf{x}; \pi(\textbf{h})\right) \text{d}\textbf{h}$$

where  $\pi(\textbf{h}) = \frac{\left(1, e^{h_1}, \dots, e^{h_d}\right)}{1+e^{h_1}+\dots+e^{h_d}}$, $N\left(\textbf{h}; \boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}\right)$ the multivariate normal distribution and $\text{Mult}\left(\textbf{x}; \pi\right)$ is the multinomial distribution, identifiable?

I.e. $$P(\textbf{x}; \boldsymbol{\mu}_1, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1) = P(\textbf{x}; \boldsymbol{\mu}_2, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_2) \implies \boldsymbol{\mu_1} = \boldsymbol{\mu_2} \text{ and } \boldsymbol{\Sigma_1} = \boldsymbol{\Sigma_2}$$

I've found different sources dealing with a similar problem but I fail to find a final answer.

- Lindsay, B. G. (1995). Mixture Models: Theory, Geometry and Applications. Institute of Mathematical Statistics (Vol. 5).
- Chandra, S. (1977). On the mixtures of probability distributions. Scandinavian Journal of Statistics, 4, 105–112.
- Hasselblad, V. (1969). Estimation of Finite Mixtures of Distributions from the Exponential Family. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 64(328), 1459–1471.

Comment: What space does $\mathbf x$ live in?  What multinomial sample sizes are you contemplating?  Just one, all possible, or what?

Comment: I assume $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{N}^{d+1}$. I had no restriction of type $\sum_i x_i =n$ in mind. But if with such restriction there is some result, I would be also interested in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know the values of $P(\mathbf x;\mathbf \mu,\mathbf \Sigma)$ for all $\mathbf x$ is to know all the mixed moments of the random vector $\pi(\mathbf h)$ and hence (because the range of $\pi$ is bounded) the distribution of the random vector $\pi(\mathbf h)$.

This follows from the algebraic form of the multinomial probability function:  $P(\mathbf x|\mathbf \pi)= m(\mathbf x) \mathbf \pi^{\mathbf x}$ where $m(\mathbf x)$ denotes the multinomial coefficient for count vector $\mathbf x$ and 
${\mathbf \pi}^{\mathbf x} =\prod \pi_i^{x_i}$.  So the compound multinomial probability function $P(\mathbf x)=E[ P(\mathbf x|\mathbf \pi)] $ that you get when you take the expectation over $\mathbf \pi$ is thus  equal to $m(\mathbf x)$ times the $\mathbf x$-th moment of the random vector $\mathbf \pi$.  (The $\mathbf x$-th moment with respect to the mixing distribution for $\mathbf \pi$.)  Finally, its a technical fact that the moments of a random vector distributed over a compact set, like the $d+1$ probability simplex, as your $\pi(\mathbf h)$ is, uniquely specifies the the distribution of that random vector.

So the question reduces to asking if the distribution of $\pi(\mathbf h)$ is identifiable.

Which it is:  the map $\mathbf h\mapsto\pi(\mathbf h)$ is invertible, so to know the distribution of $\pi(\mathbf h)$ is to know the distribution of $\mathbf h$.

Why is $\pi(\mathbf h)$  invertible? We can recover $\mathbf x=(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ by $h_i = \log(\pi_i(\mathbf h)/\pi_0(\mathbf h))$, when we number the subscripts $0$ through $d$.

Comment: Thanks @kimchi. But in your reasoning I don't understand the role that the multivariate normal and the multinomial distribution are playing.

Comment: I have tried to address this in an edit.  Do you understand why the corresponding result for mixed binomial r.v,.s holds?

Comment: So, at the end, identifiability comes from the identifiability of the multivariate normal rv H. I think I can understant that. I've never seen the result for mixed binomial rv. Do you have some reference?

Comment: The all $\mathbf x\in \mathbb N^{d+1}$ assumption is pretty strong, and allows the problem to be reduced this way to identifiability of the multivariate normal. The paper https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1017939148 covers the binomial case with fixed sample size case, which is possibly more realistic.